# How do I set a counter for a cookie information pop up window that does not get set back to 0 when I navigate though subpages?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookies, counter

I want to pop up a cookie information when the main page is loaded but when the user navigates through the subpages and returns to the main page, the cookie information should not pop up again.
So far I am using the following code but I do not know how to implement my requirements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!Cookies.get('alert')) { 
      $('.cookiepopup2').show(); 
      Cookies.set('alert', true, { expires: 1 });
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code seems fine and should theoretically work. What's not working?

Comment: When I navigate through the subpages and return to the main page, the cookie information comes up again.

Comment: What does `Cookies.get('alert')` return when logging it? And is the cookie actually set in the browser. In Chrome check the `application` tab and see if your cookie is in the list.

Comment: What is `Cookies` here? Is that an object coming from a plugin? And I doubt about `expires: 1`... Where it usually should be a date.

Comment: Another thing I think of is the value of the cookie probably is a string. So I would try `if (!Boolean(Cookies.get('alert')))`.